# Is there a way to change the color of one marker using gmaps4rails v2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

So I want to change the color of one marker pin on my map, and I have the following:

```
bool = false
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@branches) do |branch, marker|
  if bool == false
    marker.lat x
    marker.lng y
    marker.infowindow "YOUR LOCATION"
    marker.fillColor "blue"
    bool = true
  else
    marker.lat branch.latitude
    marker.lng branch.longitude
  end
end
```

Unfortunately I receive the error: `undefined method 'fillColor' for #<Gmaps4rails::MarkersBuilder::MarkerBuilder:0x00000018003f58>`

**I have seen other answers that suggest customizing the marker with an image, but this seems like overkill for my case.**

UPDATE:

I have added the following to my view script:

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  //markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  var jsonCollection = <%= raw @hash.to_json %>;
  var particularMarker = _.first(jsonCollection);
  var collection = _.rest(jsonCollection);
  var markers = handler.addMarkers(collection)
  markers << handler.addMarker(particularMarker,{ opacity: 0.5 })
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

I wasn't sure if fillColor was even an option in the API for markers, so I tried out opacity 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

I don't see any change in the marker, but I have verified that the marker is present, as seen in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not builtin but maybe you could do something like:

```
var jsonCollection = <%= raw @hash.to_json %>;
var particularMarker = _.first(jsonCollection);
var collection = _.rest(jsonCollection);

handler.addMarker(particularMarker,{ fillColor: 'blue' })
handler.addMarkers(collection)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the direction I'm looking for. Please see my update.

Comment: dont know why it fails for you but t works for me :) http://plnkr.co/edit/59NfGPVqJe78vFLpCsfL?p=preview

Comment: I added the script src from your plnkr and now it works. Maybe update the javascript dependencies on your github page to <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.18&sensor=false&client=&key=&libraries=geometry&language=&hl=&region="></script>
<script src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

Comment: Suggest changes in a pull request, i'd gladly accept